# Power BI bookmark conflicts with slicers

Tags: bookmarks, microsoft-powerbi

I ran into a bookmark/slicer issue in Power BI. When I try to set a bookmark with more than one filtering setting, I have to update the bookmark every month.

My general bookmarks point to a certain page, and the date filtering works well between the two. However, when I try to set a bookmark based on more than one slicer, then the bookmarks have to be updated every month, which is very annoying at the least. My general bookmarks do not need to be updated at all.

Is this a limitation of PBI? Or is there a work-around to getting two or more slicers (for example: product line and date) in a bookmark without needing to update it every time data is updated?

Comment: This forum is for computer enthusiasts and power users. Power BI is a MS business analytics. Try posting on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi

Comment: @tiagoams That's funny, I was told to go here from there because my question didn't have to do with programming explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure out what your issue is, so here's some general info that hopefully gets you unblocked.

Power BI's Bookmarks feature is poorly documented, this blog/tips page explains the options in more detail.  In particular, you might need to try the **Selected Visuals** setting for your challenge.

https://powerbi.tips/2021/06/power-bi-bookmarks-tips/#h-change-power-bi-bookmark-settings

Answer (score 0):

If you click a bookmark within the Bookmarks pane, you can select "All Visuals" or "Selected Visuals". Check Selected Visuals and turn off the relationship to the slicer.